# Laravel dynamic route with dynamic prefix

Tags: php, laravel, routes, prefix

I would like to add the customer_id before each group route with the following approach. The customer_id is set as Session::get('customer.id').

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'customer/{id}'], function($id) {
        Route::get('reports/default', array('as' => 'customer_reports_path', 'uses' => 'ReportController@getDefault'))->before('customer'); 
        Route::get('data/objects/{$object_id}', array('as' => 'customer_reports_object', 'uses' => 'DataController@getObject'));
});
```

The first route works as aspected, however, I don't know how to use the second one correctly.

```
{{ HTML::link(route('customer_reports_object', [Session::get('customer.id'), $object_id], 'Object name') }}
```

The link still ends in 404.

Comment: Your syntax on that code is a bit off. Try this: `{{ link_to_route('customer_reports_object', 'Object name', [Session::get('customer.id'), $object_id]) }}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@MichaelColeman is right `$` signs are not allow in route parameters. And here is why:

The route parameters are found by a Regex, which only matches `\w` (words) and `$` is not included.

`Illuminate\Routing\Route@compileRoute`

```
$uri = preg_replace('/\{(\w+?)\?\}/', '{$1}', $this->uri);
```

The solution is obviously to remove the `$` (it was probably a typo in the first place)

```
Route::get('data/objects/{object_id}'...
```

And to generate your link correctly. (I also suggest you use the `link_to_route` function)

```
{{ link_to_route('customer_reports_object', 'Object name', [Session::get('customer.id'), $object_id]) }}
```

Comment: cool, probably worth noting also - that the `link_to_route` function actually uses the *literal* syntax  "link_to_route" - otherwise your previous comment read (to me anyway) like `{{insert_your_route_here('custome....) }}`.  i.e. `link_to_route is a laravel helper function <http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers>

Answer (score 1):

Try without the `$` in the parameter i.e.

```
Route::get('data/objects/{object_id}', array('as' => 'customer_reports_object', 'uses' => 'DataController@getObject'));
```

Comment: great, can you post what the actual (corrected) code you needed to use in your HTML to get the link working please, I would be interested to see what you used

Comment: dont worry, I see what @lukasgeiter meant now